# How Serve Angular App from location other than the root of the server and get your urls to work

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-routing

Issue:

Angular App is built and embedded into a class library, when the project runs, user navigates to https://example.com/Admin and the angular app with the class library is loaded.

The resulting url is expected to be https://example.com/Admin#/home

What I get is https://example.com/#/home

How do I preserve the /Admin, while still allowing the angular scripts to load from the root wwwroot folder from asp.net core?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is struggling with URL re-writing issues.  The bulk of the problem lies with how angular determines "what is my base URL" before changing it.

By Default, your index.html file will have a `<base href="/" />` in it.  This is the starting point for how angular builds your script/css/content *and* your router URLs.

So, in this case, changing this to `<base href="/Admin" />` solved my issue.

**Important:** I tried adding `<base href="/Admin/" />` so my urls would look like `https://example.com/Admin/#/home` with the extra `/` on the end of my MVC routes. This broke my script loading as it tried to load all of the content from /Admin.  By leaving of the trailing `/` angular apparently ignores it when building your content URLs, but **still uses it for the Routing**.

More on [Location Strategies](https://www.netjstech.com/2020/09/location-strategies-in-angular-routing.html#:%7E:text=In%20Angular%20there%20are%20two%20LocationStrategy%20providers-%201.,%28a%20hash%20%27%23%27%29%20as%20the%20client-side%20URL%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F%23%2Faccount) that helped me realize how the URL's are being written out.